# Ramanujan graph girth comparision

Tags: graphs

I am working on Ramanujan graphs and have encountered something that needs a suggestion. Does the girth of a Ramanujan graph change if I delete one random edge from the graph? 
 The question can also be as follows: are there at least two edge-disjoint shortest cycles in Ramanujan graphs? If yes, the girth does not change if I delete some random edge.

Comment: do you mean "arbitrary" instead of "random"?

Comment: yes I meant arbitrary.